# Any YAML based fixture loader for Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, yaml, fixtures, playframework

I've used [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) but after playing about with the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) recently I've found it's [Fixtures.load(String yamlFilename)](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.2.1/test#aFixturesa) really useful. Anyone know of a similar tool that can be used with any Java project?

Comment: The DbUnit link points to some Chinese advertisement. Could you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical, I found the answer immediately after posting the question. Looks like [JYaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/) is what I'm after. The first time I seen this tool I just glanced at [YAML4DbUnit](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/yaml4dbunit.html)  and thought it was just an extension to DbUnit.

Comment: Actually I ditched JYaml in the end in and went with SnakeYAML. No particular reason. I just felt more comfortable with it since JYaml hadn't had a release since 2007.

Comment: JYaml is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in my project, [Fixy](https://github.com/sberan/Fixy), which creates fixtures and loads them into a JPA context for querying. It supports includes, package declaration, and processors. It's very similar to Play's fixture mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Fixjures: https://code.google.com/archive/p/fixjures/

2.0-rc1 includes YAML support. The library supports POJOs and interface proxies.

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks Steve.